# Use a temp table in a Table-valued Functions

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, function, temp-tables

I'm trying to use a temp table in a table-valued function, but it seems I can not.  Is there any other way I can use a temp table in a table-valued function?

CURRENT CODE:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnt_AllChildren (@ParentName VARCHAR(255))
  RETURNS @return_variable TABLE 
    (
        Id INT,
        Name VARCHAR(255),
        ParentId INT,
        ParentName VARCHAR(255)
    )
AS
BEGIN
    CREATE TABLE #Child (Id INT, Name VARCHAR(255), ParentId INT, ParentName VARCHAR(255))
    CREATE TABLE #Parent (Id INT, Name VARCHAR(255), ParentId INT, ParentName VARCHAR(255))


    INSERT #Child (Id, Name, ParentId, ParentName)
    SELECT child.Id, child.Name, child.ParentId, parent.Name
    FROM dbo.t_mytable child
    INNER JOIN dbo.t_mytable parent ON child.ParentId = parent.Id
    WHERE parent.Name = @ParentName

    WHILE (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @return_variable
        SELECT * FROM #Child

        DELETE FROM#Parent

        INSERT INTO #Parent
        SELECT * FROM #Child

        DELETE FROM #Child
        
        INSERT INTO #Child (Id, Name, ParentId, ParentName)
        SELECT child.Id, child.Name, child.ParentId, parent.Name
        FROM dbo.t_mytable child
        INNER JOIN #Parent parent ON child.ParentId = parent.Id
    END
    RETURN
END
GO
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use a [table variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188927.aspx) instead.

```
DECLARE @Child TABLE (Id INT, Name VARCHAR(255), ParentId INT, ParentName VARCHAR(255))
DECLARE @Parent TABLE (Id INT, Name VARCHAR(255), ParentId INT, ParentName VARCHAR(255))
```

Answer (score 4):

No.

You can use `@table_variables` though. Although from a quick glance maybe a [recursive CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186243.aspx) might work for you rather than using these child/parent tables at all.